Product formula for $\dfrac{4}{\pi}$
Can someone give me a hint on how to prove the following formula:
$$\frac{4}{\pi}=\left(\prod_{p \equiv 1 \pmod{5} \atop p \in \mathbb{P} } \frac{p}{p+1}\right) \cdot \left(\prod_{p \equiv 2 \pmod{5} \atop p \in \mathbb{P} } \frac{p}{p+2}\right) \cdot \left(\prod_{p \equiv 3 \pmod{5} \atop p \in \mathbb{P} } \frac{p}{p-2}\right) \cdot \left(\prod_{p \equiv 4 \pmod{5} \atop p \in \mathbb{P} } \frac{p}{p-1}\right)$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes set of prime numbers.
Pari/GP code
I think that proof of Euler product formula can be useful but I am not sure. Perhaps some other approach exists.

May I ask where is the expression from?

@Zima I formulated it.

@Pedja, your post does not contain enough context. You should add your efforts and attempts in order to solve your problem.

The products are divergent

You may have to order the fractions by ascending value of the prime to get convergence and the target, thus $(2/4)×(3/1)×(7/9)×(11/12)×...$.

As something of a ground rule, we might require the factors to be listed in order of increasing value of the prime, so that the different residues $\bmod 5$ are mixed together and thus cancel out, by "interference", the divergent tendencies.
Given a list of consecutive primes starting with $2$, the denominator associated with a prime numerator $p$ is determined by the formula
$2p-5\lfloor(\frac{p}5+\frac{1}{2})\rfloor$
where the second term rounds the prime to the nearest multiple of $5$.
Thus
$2\to(2×2-5×0)=4,3\to(2×3-5×5)=1,$
etc and we get the fractions
$\frac24,\frac31,\frac55,\frac79,...$
whose cumulated products then seem to be approaching the target value $4/\pi$ indicated by the heavy orange horizontal line:


A better established product involving $\bmod 5$ residues of primes is as follows:
$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt5}=+\frac11+\frac13+\frac17+\frac19-\frac1{11}-\frac1{13}-\frac1{17}-\frac1{19}...$
$=(\frac32)(\frac76)(\frac{11}{12})(\frac{13}{14})...$
$=\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}-\{2,5\}}\dfrac{p}{p+(-1)^{(p+1)/2}(p|5)}$
The infinite series comes from Dirichlet $L$-functions (it may also be derived using a properly constructed Fourier series evaluation). The denominators end with $1,3,7,9$ in base ten and the signs repeat the eight-cycle shown. Converting this to the Euler product form gives the result with the general term indicated in the last line and $(p|5)$ being the Legendre symbol.

Experimental data suggests that the product converges,  but to a value less than $4/\pi$. I computed the product for the first $1.8 \times 10^9$ primes. The results are as follows:

Upto $2 \times 10^7$ primes, product $= 1.27307779$
Upto $1.8 \times 10^9$ primes, product $= 1.27307727$

and the product has been pretty much flat around this value upto six decimal places without any tendency to increase upto $4/\pi \approx 1.27323954$. The product agrees with $4/\pi$ to only three decimal places so this think this is just a coincidence.
Update 27-Aug: Infact, the data seems to be consistent with
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} = \prod_{p \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \atop p \in \mathbb{P} } \frac{p}{p-1} \cdot
\prod_{p \equiv 3 \pmod{4} \atop p \in \mathbb{P} } \frac{p}{p+1}.
$$
For the first $10^9$ primes the product agrees with $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to seven decimal places.
Update 29-Aug: My data shows that for any $n \ge 2$
$$
\prod_{r < n \atop p \in P} \left(\prod_{p \equiv r \bmod 2n} \frac{p}{p-1}\right) \cdot
\prod_{r > n \atop p \in P} \left(\prod_{p \equiv r \bmod 2n} \frac{p}{p+1}\right)\tag 5
$$
is some algebraic multiple of $\pi$. I have asked this as a separate question here: Product formulas for $\pi$ using prime numbers

This seems right to me. Aitken extrapolation suggests this is tending toward 1.273077... I didn't compute as far as you but your results are consistent with mine.

Between $10^{10}$ and $10^{11}$, the product is between 1.2730764 and 1.2730779. (This corresponds to the ~4.11e9-th prime; the product up to $10^{11}$ is 1.27307688.)

The formula you mentioned in the update is true, the RHS is the Euler product for the L-function attached to the unique primitive Dirichlet character of modulus 4.
